# Divide a list of elements into 2 to 3 columns depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive, display

So I have to upgrade an old site (the hardcoded-style tier old site) into a 2k17 responsive website. So I'm basically using CSS and HTML (also PHP and Javascript but for the controller and model interactions - I'd like to avoid it as much as possible because clean code matters).

Once again, if possible, I'd like to have an HTML/CSS based solution, thank you.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and its grid display to make it work, but there's one page that bothers me.

I have a list of elements I would like to display in a table that would be composed of two or three columns depending on the screen size (see the image below).

[The type of display I'd like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG5pr.png)

/!\ The order of the elements must be preserved.

/!\ The columns have to be separated to make it look like a table.

I'm afraid I'm not good enough with boostrap to figure out how to do it.

NB : I'm coding "thinking about little resolutions first" so the image might be misleading.

Any hint is appreciated :)

Comment: did you try anything. see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Wouldn't it be more readable to display each column as a row on mobile device (espacially on small screen which have to scroll to read the start of the "2" section then scroll back to read the rest of it with your current illustration)?

Comment: Also, can you provide your actual code?

Comment: it is very simple, creat element like 1 2 2(part1) 2(part2) 3, for pc show the big 2, for the mobile show 2(part1) 2(part2)

Comment: About the display, I can't change it since the company I'm working for wants this specific display.
For the same reason I can't provide a code sample.

I wanted to see if there was a solution that wouldn't be as bruteforced as having two different displays for the two different resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been fiddling with some JQuery and CSS, which might help you.

Basically changes some styles with CSS using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
}
```

To change the CSS if the screen is smaller than 500px (You, of course, can change 500 to whatever you want). For this to work, you need to use a meta tag in the HTML `<head>`, like so;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Also used JQuery to move elements when the screen width = 500.

**EDIT:**

As the OP is not able to use JQuery, pure CSS is required. This may cause problems, but having two tables and showing only one when using pc and showing the other on tablet/mobile phone may be the best option.

```
#mobile {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  #pc {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Then you just need to create two tables; One with the desired PC outcome, and one with the desired mobile outcome, with the id's of 'pc' and 'mobile'.

Working demo on CodePen: http://codepen.io/JamesDouglas/pen/wdNZMN

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, sadly, my company won't accept if I provide a code that would break the display, and I'm not allowed to use any kind of JS (they'd rather have me using two different divs that would display or not depending on the size).

Comment: Ok then, perhaps you could mention that in the question? Anyway, I will work on the new code :)